# Log changes through database-scoped DML triggers

Tags: sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2014

is it possible to create database-scoped DML triggers ?

I'm planning to set a log mechanism on my database, and I was thinking of using a database-scoped after insert, update and delete triggers instead of having to define individual triggers for each table.

Is it possible ?, on the documentation I only see database-scoped triggers for DDL operations, not DML.

Comment: No, Triggers for DML are against objects, like Tables and Views. Every object is different, so you couldn't create a "standard" one at database level. If, however, you have a very rigid method you want to implement on all the tables, you could use dynamic SQL to create them all, however, we don't have enough information to even begin to help you on that (and I suggest having a go yourself first if that's the route you want to take).

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want to do in the way you want to do it, but you can fairly easily make a generator that will go through the system data dictionary for a table and generate audit tables and triggers for it.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, that's what I thought.